# space validation in js?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to restrict the use of space on the website name (here)..

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <h4>Website Name</h4>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="wname" id="wname" size="30" required  onfocus="validateWebsite();" oninput="validateWebsite();">
        <select name="domain">
            <option selected>.com</option>
            <option>.in</option>
            <option>.net</option>
            <option>.org</option>
            <option>.edu</option>
            <option>.int</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And the `main.js` file contains the following code.
I want to restrict the user to enter the space. With the available code it's not working:

```
function validateWebsite()  {
    var s = document.getElementById('wname');
    if (s.indexOf(" ") !== -1){
        wname.setCustomvalidity('');
    }else{
        wname.setCustomValidity('Invalid Website');
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? I don't see any question marks. Please take a minute or two to think about what you are asking.

Comment: @jurgemaister i want to restrict the use of space on the 'website name' field

Comment: I'd say: trim the value of `#wname` and don't bother the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
    var s = document.getElementById('wname').value;
    if(s.trim().length == 0 || s.trim().indexOf(' ') != -1)
    {
         // Your code when string is just blank or having spaces
    }
    else
    {
         // Your code when string is not blank and not having any spaces
    }
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
if (s.indexOf(" ") !== -1)
```

Should be:

```
if (s.value.indexOf(" ") === -1)
```

Also, the first `setCustomvalidity` is misspelled (lowercase 'v').